# Why my map is like this?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using this simple tutorial: [a simple google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=fr). I used other tutorials and I got the same result: my map is not clear as you can see in the following pic:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=fr

Comment: please share your MapActivity Code..!!

Answer (score 1):

you can change  map type by using following code

```
 map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

The Google Maps Android API offers four types of maps, as well as an option to have no map at all:

**Normal**
Typical road map. Roads, some man-made features, and important natural features such as rivers are shown. Road and feature labels are also visible.

**Hybrid**
Satellite photograph data with road maps added. Road and feature labels are also visible.

**Satellite**
Satellite photograph data. Road and feature labels are not visible.

**Terrain**
Topographic data.
 The map includes colors, contour lines and labels, and perspective shading. Some roads and labels are also visible.

More details Refer [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map)

Comment: same result for all types of maps

Comment: i'm using BlueStacks emulator

Comment: check with real device

Comment: are you emulating a low bandwith connection?

Comment: how can i check it ?